# Drupal - Rules Condition that node has been updated more than once?

Tags: drupal

Is it possible to have a Rules Condition that a node has been updated more than once?

I need different email alerts for when content is created and when its updated. The issue is that im using the Multistep module:
http://drupal.org/project/multistep

The Multistep module breaks the node creation form into 2 or more separate pages. One the first page the node is created but unpublished. When you finish all the steps the node is updated and published. I need the email to be sent after the node has had all the steps filled in, as the CCK fields are used in the email. Therefore I cant use Rules inbuilt event of 'After saving new content' and 'After updating existing content'.

How can I differentiate in Rules from when the node is first fully filled in, and when its subsequently updated? One way to do this would be to have different conditions for weather the node has been updated once or more than once. Is this possible and if so, is it the best solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this would be too look at the URL or referrer like mentioned here, http://drupal.org/node/827728. You'd have to use the Execute PHP functionality and have some knowledge of how to write a short script though.

Comment: Ive tried to have the event of 'content is going to be saved' and a condition of 'Path has alias(es)' as the url is different when the content is first created as opposed to later edited, but I cant get it working.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM:

How to test for the number of times a node has been modified.

POSSIBLE SOLUTION:

Include a "counter" field in the CCK that is hidden from the user (via CSS) and auto-incremented each time the node is accessed. Then use the value of this counter in rules conditions.

(See e.g., http://drupal.org/node/1172550 for more details)

PROBLEM:

How to treat a node differently based on whether it is being 'added' for the first time, or 'updated'.

POSSIBLE SOLUTION:

Create a path rule that is conditional on node type.
Trigger the path rule for the node/add page of the specific node type.
Pre-populate fields on the node/add page using the elementdefaults module.